# Intersection of several lists with reduce

Tags: kotlin, collections, reduce

I wanted to create a function that returns an intersection of several lists. I did something like this:

```
fun <T> List<List<T>>.intersection(): List<T> {
    return this.reduce { acc, it -> acc.apply { acc.toMutableSet().retainAll(it.toSet()) } }
}
```

I called it with `List<List<Int>>` like this `[[12, 321], [4, 35, 4], [67, 57, 8], [98, 97]]`, but it keeps returning me the first list. The expected list should be an empty list.
I added an `also` to see what this reduce is called with and it is the same (the first one) list all the time.
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here and how can I write that function with `reduce`?

Comment: In case anyone's not aware: the standard library already has an [`intersect()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html) function. (Of course, writing your own is a very valid and worthwhile exercise! But if you only want the result, then it's been done for you.)

Comment: @gidds Note that kotlin's stdlib `intersect()` returns a set, while the OP's question the method returns a `List` type, indicating some order has to be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently creates a copy of `acc` as a mutable set, removes the elements not in `it`, and then does nothing with it.  You never actually save or return the results.  `acc.apply` only reflects modifications actually made to `acc`, not anything you did with copies of `acc`.

Comment: Make sense, it creates a new set so I am changing something different than I expected.
To be honest I didn't understand the hint with removing `apply`,, but the first part about a copy of `acc` showed me the problem.
The current solution:
```fun <T> List<List<T>>.intersection(): List<T> {
    return this.toMutableSet().map { it.toMutableSet() }.reduce { acc, it -> acc.apply { retainAll(it.toSet()) } }.toList()
}```
If you can, please show the solution without `acc.apply` 
Thanks!